# Jquery Why is my div fading in and out and in again?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

So I have a simple button that hovers at the bottom of the screen that when click it scrolls back to the top of the page. The problem is when click the button begins to fade out, then back in, and then back out once it gets to the top.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="backToTop">
<a href="#top">Top</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {            
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).height() + 100) {
            $('.backToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.backToTop').fadeOut();
        }
});

$('.backToTop a').click(function () {
        var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
        var sub = anchor.substring(anchor.search('#'));
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest solution: don't use a **link**.

Because you use javascript you don't need the `a href` at all, you can use a `span` instead, this way the click doesn't trigger other scroll events.

```
<div class="backToTop">
    <span>Top</span>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/UmYgG/

**Bonus:**
Here is a bug, can you spot it?

```
   $(window).scroll(function () {            
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).height() + 100) {
                $('.backToTop').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('.backToTop').fadeOut();
            }
    });
```

`$(this)` reffers to the window, not to your element. It should be `$('.backToTop')` . You will never reach `scrollTop` larger then window height.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you click the link to go back to the top of the page, it triggers the scroll event as well. One solution would be to set a flag when you click the link, like this:

```
var showBackToTop = true;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).height() + 100 && showBackToTop) {
        $('.backToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.backToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

$('.backToTop a').click(function () {
    showBackToTop = false;
    var anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    var sub = anchor.substring(anchor.search('#'));
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800, 'swing', function(){showBackToTop = true;});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that jQuery actually uses a queue for animations, this includes fadeIn/fadeOut.

Because so many scroll events are fired when scrolling the window, it will actually queue up those fadeIn/fadeOut animations.

In order to prevent it from doing that, you may want to use the `.stop()` jQuery function. Which stops the previous animation prevents it from finishing and starts the next function in the chain.

Example:

```
...
    $('.backToTop').stop().fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.backToTop').stop().fadeOut();
}
...
```

The other thing you could do if this doesn't work for you for some reason, is to set a timer that runs the code in the scroll method and gets cleared every time you scroll. It will cause a slight delay for when the link shows or hides though and that may not be ideal.

Comment: If you do this, the animation will never play, because scroll event is triggered very fast.

Comment: I digress, Cristy's answer is much better!